# ImportError: No module named folium?

Tags: python, importerror, folium

I Tried Installing folium with :

```
pip install folium
```

And:

```
conda install -c conda-forge folium
```

And I Tried Installing Specific Version too But It Still doesn't work. When I Try The Installing Commands Again I Just Get This:

```
    Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
    Requirement already satisfied: folium==0.11.0 in /home/rem/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages 
    (0.11.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: jinja2>=2.9 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from 
    folium==0.11.0) (2.10.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: branca>=0.3.0 in /home/rem/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages 
    (from folium==0.11.0) (0.4.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from folium==0.11.0) 
    (2.22.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/rem/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from
    folium==0.11.0) (1.18.5)
```

Also I Tried:

```
conda install branca
```

Or :

```
pip install branca
```

And I Still Get This ERROR:

```
            line 1, in <module>
     import folium
ImportError: No module named folium
```

PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: try `conda install branca` and `pip install branca`. Is the error shown here the full error?

Comment: @snatchysquid      Yes That's The Full Error

Comment: branca is already installed

Comment: Are you sure you are running the code and the installation for the same python environment/version?

Comment: @89f3a1c   Yes I'm Sure 100%

Comment: So `pip list` has `folium` in it? For me, `pip install folium` and them `import folium` just works...

Comment: @futaba It could be that you're pip installing with a different python than you're using for running script. Do next thing: 1) suppose for running script you use `python3` binary i.e. `python3 some_script.py`. 2) then you need to install with same python binary like this `python3 -m pip install folium`. Or if pip install doesn't work then [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64075339/941531) can be used, but also with same python binary `python3 -m pip install ...whl`. 3) after installation use same python binary for scripts like `python3 my_script.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always possible to manually download and instaly any `pip` package using `wheelodex` site like this:

1. Go to https://www.wheelodex.org/projects/folium/.
2. Follow [download link](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a4/f0/44e69d50519880287cc41e7c8a6acc58daa9a9acf5f6afc52bcc70f69a6d/folium-0.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl) on the page above, you'll get `folium-0.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl` file.
3. Install file using `pip` like `python -m pip install folium-0.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`.

You may install other non-working packages too in similar way.